# Android browser shake detection with javascript for a web application

Tags: javascript, android, mobile-website, shake

Do any versions of androids web browser detect javascript shake events? Something like this:
`window.addEventListener('devicemotion', this, false);`
I can't seem to find any information on this.
I am using WKShake which is refrenced here: [Javascript. Listen for iPhone shake event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202216/javascript-listen-for-iphone-shake-event)
and am wondering if this is going to work on android as well.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112369/how-to-shake-on-android-2-2

Comment: @josh, that looks like android code to me. I asked about javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I have discovered that the android browser does not have access to accelerometer data.  Perhaps some time in the future they will allow the browser to access this data.

Answer (score 1):

Shake.js (http://functionn.blogspot.com/2012/03/shakejs-custom-shake-event-javascript.html) is a custom 'shake' event JavaScript plugin for mobile web browsers using device accelerometer.  Your web browser must support the devicemotion event for this plugin to work.  Shake.js uses built-in feature detection to determine if it can run in your web browser.  It will terminate silently on non-supporting browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of a JavaScript shake method for Android built on top of PhoneGap's accelerometer API - [github link](https://github.com/paulb777/NameTrendz/blob/master/www/shaker.js)

Comment: this is closer to what I'm after, but again, I'm wanting to see this work in the browser, not a phone gap native applicaiton.

Comment: @jtmkrueger As your answer says, the browser doesn't have direct access to the accelerometer, as well as a bunch of other device capabilities. That is the "Gap" that PhoneGap is designed to fill.